# Where does Flex looking for crossdomain.xml

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash, flashdevelop

Can anyone please describe what is the flash pipeline when looking for crossdomain.xml file?

I am sometimes receive SECURITY_ERROR (#2700) from flash.
Trying to find the issue, I'd like to understand better the crossdomain loading pipeline.
I mean, Does it looks first in cached files in my browser? What does it do when going to server?

For example, I thought about such solution:

- I'll put the link resources into html page Head section to download crossdomain before I am loading my flash object
- In case of failure - I'll try to handle this from JS and notify server (somehow, not the issue)
- But if the file was downloaded during html page loading - **does it ensure me that flash will be able to load it?** (may be from cached documents?)

I am completely-unfamiliar with this domain, so any help will be more than appreciated!

Comment: Maybe [my Apache module or Perl script](https://github.com/afarber/mod-socket-policy) will help you here.

Comment: I think that you meant Security Error #2070 which a Security sandbox violation error, but I don't understand what's your problem exactly ?

Comment: @akmozo yes, sorry - I mean #2070 error. My problem that flash sometimes (not each time, but eventually) failed with this error for clients, when nothing changed from my side. I am trying to troubleshout / decrease this failures

Comment: So I am looking to identify crossdomain.xml file access issues. One of the solutions I come from is to pre-load this file in flash's host html page. But I did not understand - will flash in this case try to re-download it from server, or will use already downloaded file. 
Am I completly wrong about something?

Comment: Usually a sandbox security error is not related directly with crossdomain.xml which is used in the case of a cross-domain problems. So I think that you waste your time when you concentrate in the crossdomain.xml loading problem because : 1st, that's not your real problem, 2nd, if this file exist, the Flash player will get it without any problem, from the cache if it's available or directly from the server ( if the cache version didn't exist or it's obsolete ). So if you have a specific code that generate usually the problem, put it to see it may be we can find the real problem to solve it.